# MongoDB C++ Update array and add element

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-cxx-driver

I want to update the "user"-array of the following JSON-document which is saved in a MongoDB Database (programming language C++)

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ac4beacc0e2a512e6377d43"),
        "document" : "test",
        "user" : [
            {
                "email" : "a@gmail.com",
                "username" : "Anton Held",
                "job" : "",
            },
            {
                "email" : "b@gmail.com",
                "username" : "Benny Bill",
                "job" : "IT-Officer",
            },
            {
                "email" : "c@gmail.com",
                "username" : "Conny Cenn",
                "job" : "",
            },
        ]
    }
```

Therefore I am using this command to get this specific document:

```
collection.update_one(document{} << "document" << "test"
                                     << finalize,
                      document{} << "$set" << open_document <<
                                 (HOW TO DEAL?!) close_document << finalize);
```

I know that it is possible to update a document with the "update_one"-method (or similar methods like "replace_one", "find_one_and_replace").

But I don't know how to deal with this methods to update as example the username of the existing user with the "email"-element="a@gmail.com" or how I could add a user to the existing array "user".

Please help me :-)

Comment: Okay that works with this command, but i am not able to convert this to C++: db.getCollection('testcollection').update({"document":"test",
                                               "user.email":"a@gmail.com"},
                                       {"$set": {"user.$.username":"New Username"}})

Please take a look at my last example :collection.update_one(document{} << "document" << "test"
                                     << finalize,
                      document{} << "$set" << open_document <<
                                 (HOW TO DEAL?!) close_document << finalize);

Answer (score 2):

So you question boils down to *how to convert this mongo command to C++ code*:

```
db.getCollection("testcollection").update(
   {"document":"test", "user.email":"a@gmail.com"},
   {"$set": {"user.$.username":"New Username"}}
)
```

Here's how it can look like. Notice the pattern:

- Output keys and values in pairs
- Use `open_document` and `close_document` for nested `{` and `}`

Sample result:

```
collection.update_one(
  document{} << "document" << "test"
             << "user.email" << "a@gmail.com"
             << finalize,
  document{} << "$set"
             << open_document
                 << "user.$.username" << "New Username"
             << close_document << finalize
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) says, you can do as follow to add a new user:

```
db.getCollection("testcollection").update(
   { "document": "test"},
   { "$push": {
         "user": {
             "username":"A new user in town ;)",
             "email": "cooluser@gmail.com"
             "job": "A cool job for a cool user"
         }
     }
   }
)
```

In mongodbcxx:

As [@rustyx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49717474/8038186) mentioned you can simply change `{}` to open/close document and to get:

```
collection.update_one(
  document{}
      << "document" << "test"
      << finalize,

  document{}
      << "$push" << open_document
          << "user" << open_document
              << "username" << "A new user in town ;)"
              << "email"    << "cooluser@gmail.com"
              << "job"      << "A cool job for a cool user"
          << close_document
      << close_document
      << finalize
);
```

BTW, I would recommend to replace "user" array name to "users", because it's users array and not a user array.

Answer (score -1):

Okay that works with this command, but i am not able to convert this to C++:

`db.getCollection('testcollection').update({"document":"test", 
                                    "user.email":"a@gmail.com"}, {"$set": 
                                    {"user.$.username":"New Username"}})`

Please take a look at my last example where I try to figure out how to update this special element "username" of the user with email="a@gmail.com":

```
collection.update_one(document{} << "document" << "test" << finalize, 
                      document{} << "$set" << open_document << 
                      (HOW TO DEAL?!) close_document << finalize);
```

Comment: This is not an answer. Use the **edit** button on the question and add it to the question itself. Then delete this answer.